# i start build chrome extension which take pdf or txt file as input and scan text

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i want to use pdf.js but there is an issue that it is not possible to use pdf.js using cdn because of secuirty reason i tried different solution but not reach to desired output so what is the best solution you suggest.Following code is popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Amazon Order Automation</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".pdf,.txt" />
    <button id="startButton">Start Automation</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and following code is for popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
  const startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");

  startButton.addEventListener("click", async function () {
    const selectedFile = fileInput.files[0];
    if (selectedFile) {
      const fileContent = await readFileContent(selectedFile);

      if (selectedFile.name.endsWith(".pdf")) {
        const pdfText = await extractTextFromPDF(fileContent);
        const trackingIds = extractTrackingIdsFromText(pdfText);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ trackingIds });
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "startProcess" });
      } else {
        const trackingIds = extractTrackingIdsFromText(fileContent);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ trackingIds });
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "startProcess" });
      }
    }
  });

  async function readFileContent(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (event) => {
        resolve(event.target.result);
      };
      reader.onerror = (event) => {
        reject(event.target.error);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
  }

  async function extractTextFromPDF(pdfData) {
    const worker = new pdfjsWorker.PDFWorker();
    const pdf = await pdfjs.getDocument({ data: pdfData, worker }).promise;
    const textContent = [];

    for (let pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pdf.numPages; pageNum++) {
      const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNum);
      const pageText = await page.getTextContent();
      const pageString = pageText.items.map((item) => item.str).join(" ");
      textContent.push(pageString);
    }

    const fullText = textContent.join(" ");
    return fullText;
  }

  function extractTrackingIdsFromText(text) {
    return text.split("\n").filter((line) => line.trim().length > 0);
  }
});
```

i want to find specific text from pdf and txt file which satisficed some patterns

Comment: Manually download pdf.js, put it next to your popup.js and load it the same way as popup.js

Comment: now receive this error: 
Deprecated API usage: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified.
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cojcocmdijmhpflidlnpdbfjmcopifnn/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js.map: Fetch through target failed: Target not supported; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME